# how to put a entire ajax into a iframe with stringbuilder?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, stringbuilder

So I have this iframe that populates on load with this string builder and I have these button that go into this iframe and once they press the button i want this script to run i used to get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ but after putting ~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js into the src i got rid of the error but know i have the error saying Cancel is not defined.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("\n<script src=\"~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js\">function Cancel(input) { \n$.ajax({\n");    
    sb.Append(" url: \"/HomeController/Does_stuff\",\n");
    sb.Append(" data: input,\n");
    sb.Append(" processData: false,\n");
    sb.Append(" contentType: false,\n");
    sb.Append(" type: \"POST\",\n");
    sb.Append(" success: function (data) {\n");
    sb.Append(" location.reload();\n");
    sb.Append("}\n");
    sb.Append("})}</script>");
    foreach (DataRow data_rows in data.Rows)
    {

        foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid #ccc'>" + 
       data_rows[column.Name].ToString() + "</td>");

        }

        sb.Append("<td> <button onclick=\"Cancel(" + data_rows["Request Number"] + ")\">Cancel</button> </td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");

}
```

This is what the frame source looks like

```
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"> function Cancel(input) { 
    $.ajax({
     url: "/HomeController/Does_stuff",
     data: input,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     type: "POST",
     success: function (data) {
     location.reload();
    }
    })}</script>


<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;font-size: 9pt;font-family:Arial'>

<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Completed</td>
<td>
    <button type="button" value="Submit">Update</button>
</td>
<td>
    <button onclick="Cancel(12)">Cancel</button>
</td>
```

Comment: What does the rendered html in the iframe look like? You need to load jquery with one script element and have a separate element for your page script.

Comment: can you explain the You need to load jquery with one script element and have a separate element for your page script.

Comment: Load jquery (or any other library) separate from your in-document scripts `<script src="jquery.js" /><script>function Cancel() { }</script>`.

Comment: Are you saying have the it <script src=\"/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js\"> </script> then  <script src="jquery.js" /><script>function Cancel() { }</script>

Comment: You only need to load jquery once.

Comment: Got it. when i just have it like script src="jquery.js" /><script>function Cancel() { }</script> this it still saying Cancel is undefined when they press the button.

Comment: That was just for a short example. Use the full path as you had it.

Comment: I added the full path like I had it and still saying Cancel is undefined